# eclipse android save spinner value even when app is killed

Tags: android, button, save, spinner, switch-statement

I want to make this spinners selected value to be saved (forever) until you change it, and so it gets trigerd to jump it to the selected item intent. I have tried the mPres_doctor thing but I can´t get it to work...
Here is my cod.

```
android.widget.Spinner spinner3 = (android.widget.Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter4 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.dinklass, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner3.setAdapter(adapter4);

    spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                switch (arg2) {
                case 0:                 
                    //Intent intent1 = new Intent(Schema.this, EKE1A.class);
                    //startActivity(intent1);                        
                    break;

                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Schema laddas...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent eke1a = new Intent(Schema.this, EKE1A.class);
                    startActivity(eke1a);                       
                    break;
```

and so on.

Comment: shared preferences may be your solution [here](http://alchemiaandroid.altervista.org/sharedPreferencesTutorial.html) is an example of shared preferences usage

Comment: thanks man ! :D I´m going to look closer at this :)